# Getting html from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I am tring to extract this from my xml document and into my html The problem is that I get the pure text. I would like to to keep the html tags.

My code get the node

```
 <xsl:value-of select="text" />
```

The node:

```
 <text>
    <p>
    <strong>Hello</strong>
    <br/>
    <p>
    This is a text.
    </p>
 </text>
```

Now I get

```
Hello This is a text
```

without any tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing `<xsl:value-of select="text" />` which only outputs the text value of the node, use **xsl:copy-of** to make a copy of all the nodes

```
 <xsl:copy-of select="text/node()" />
```

Note the use of "node()" here, because if you just did `<xsl:copy-of select="text" />` you would get the actual **text** element copied as well, when you only want the child nodes copied.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I have been looking for.

Comment: @Time C. Only problem is my <br> tags get duplicated for som reason. <br><br>. This is not how the original xml looks like.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `<br><br>` and not `<br></br>`? Try adding `<xsl:output method="html" />` to you XSLT.

Comment: Yes I sure. I can clearly see the extra space and also the <br><br> in firebug.

Comment: Thanks. Changing <xsl:output method="xhtml" /> to <xsl:output method="html" /> fixed it.